# When trying to setup Raid Sata, and only the top sata ports detect drives

Tags: raid

I disabled CSM and enabled sata raid in the bios. After rebooting, the top 3 sata ports detect drives in the bios and windows and the bottom 3 located on the motherboard do not. Is there a solution or is only 1 sata port for each two? Motherboard MSI x570-a pro.
[image]

Comment: I suggest you read the user's manual before anything else.

Comment: The manual doesn't indicate this would occur. The you tube videos this doesn't happen as well. So something is wrong. I changed only the very 2 simple settings in the bios. CSM disabled and Sata Raid enabled like in youtube and the manual.

Comment: Actually it says it right there in pg. 4 (Euro version): *Supports RAID 0, RAID 1 and RAID 10 for X570 chipset SATA storage devices* [or] *Support RAID 0, RAID 1 and RAID 10 for M.2 NVME storage devices*

Comment: ok, so why would those raid options mean only half the sata ports recognize hard drives? I already knew those were the options because those are the only ones listed in raid xpert 2 configuration utility after rebooting. I haven't enabled the hard drive or created the array yet.

Comment: Ok, I think I see where you're going with this. The raid drives have to be on the top and bottom sata ports for each raid array? I've never done this before.

Comment: no, there's something wrong with my setup. I swapped around cables to fit the raid drives on top and bottom and now a random assortment of drives appear. Some that were visible before and I didn't move now don't appear.

Comment: Do you have an m.2 device in the M2_2 slot? It might be "stealing" a port from the sata devices... https://i.stack.imgur.com/whzeu.jpg suggests that only sata ports 3-6 will support raid as those are the ones off the chipset. The motherboard manual shows that would be the 4 ports closest to the RAM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5TnP.jpg